# need jQuery confirmation message emitted during asp.net postback logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog, confirm

I have a "registration" type webform in ASP.Net. When the user clicks the submit button, Page.IsPostBack code updates a database and "informs user" that redirection to Login page will occur. This all works OK but is quite ugly and I would like to make it more "elegant". Here is a snippet of my current technique clipped from Page_Load (IsPostBack):

```
Dim wrapper As New StringBuilder
Dim inner As New StringBuilder
inner.Append("Company ID ") 'txtCompanyID
inner.Append(Convert.ToString(Me.txtCompanyID.Text))
inner.Append(" has been successfully created. ")
inner.Append("\nYou will now be redirected so you can Login for the first time.")
wrapper.Append("<script language='javascript'>")
wrapper.Append("window.alert('")
wrapper.Append(inner.ToString())        'inject real message into wrapper
wrapper.Append("');")
wrapper.Append("window.location.href='")
wrapper.Append("../Login.aspx';")
wrapper.Append("</script>")
Response.Write(wrapper.ToString())
```

I have a little experience using jQuery UI dialog as a more styled alternative to Javascript - but these dialogs get invoked from client-side click events and I can't see how to inject jQuery into the above approach (I suspect there must be a better technique but I just can't find it yet).

Ideally, I'd want a nicely styled confirmation message where clicking an OK button takes the user to the specified new page.

Comment: Check this: http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2010/12/18/part-2-showing-asp-net-validation-summary-in-a-custom-dialog-server-side.aspx

Answer (score 0):

@gbs - thanks for the suggestion. From that and some more research and testing I came up with a solution I'll try to summarize here for future poor rookies like me:

**First**, the IsPostBack logic in the .aspx reduces down to constructing a message which will be the main inner content of the jQuery UI dialog and passing it to new common sub. So, the code in the OP is as follows:

```
Dim inner As New StringBuilder
inner.Append("Success! Your account has been created.<br/><br/>")
inner.Append("A confirmation email message has been sent to you.<br/><br/>")
inner.Append("Just click OK and you will be redirected to <b>Login</b> for the first time.")
UIF.MsgBoxJQUI(inner.ToString(), "TCB Welcomes You", "OK", "../Login.aspx")
```

**Next**, in a common classes library project referenced by the UI, I added this:

```
Public Class UIFunction

    Public Shared Sub MsgBoxJQUI(ByVal htmlMsg As String, _
        Optional ByVal title As String = "Please note:", _
        Optional ByVal caption As String = "OK", _
        Optional ByVal newURL As String = Nothing)
    Dim currentPage As System.Web.UI.Page = TryCast(HttpContext.Current.Handler, UI.Page)
    If currentPage IsNot Nothing Then ' use page instance..
        currentPage.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(currentPage.Page.[GetType](), _
             "dialog", _
             jQueryUIalert(htmlMsg, title, caption, newURL), _
             True)
    End If
End Sub

Private Shared Function jQueryUIalert(ByVal innerMsg As String, _
        Optional ByVal title As String = "Please note:", _
        Optional ByVal caption As String = "OK", _
        Optional ByVal newURL As String = Nothing) As String
    Dim wrapper As New StringBuilder
    wrapper.Append("$(function(){showDialog3('")
    wrapper.Append(innerMsg)       'inject real message into wrapper
    wrapper.Append("','")
    wrapper.Append(title)
    wrapper.Append("','")
    wrapper.Append(caption)
    wrapper.Append("','")
    wrapper.Append(newURL)
    wrapper.Append("')")
    wrapper.Append("});")
    Return wrapper.ToString()
End Function
```

**Next**, I added the following reference in the head of my **SiteLayout.master** page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/js/sitewide.js") %>"></script>
```

**Next**, the actual Javascript function in the sitewide.js file invokes jQuery as follows:

```
//The following function is called from the script injected from code-behind.
function showDialog3(message, title, caption, nextUrl) {
    title = title || 'Welcome to TCB';
    caption = caption || 'OK';
    nextUrl = nextUrl || '../Login.aspx';
    $('body').append("<div id='some-Message'></div>");
    $("#some-Message").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        dialogClass: 'myAlert',
        buttons: [
                {
                    text: caption,
                    click: function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            ],
        create: function() {
            $(this).closest(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-button").eq(1).addClass("deleteButtonClass");
        },
        hide: 'blind',
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        close: function(event, ui) { window.location.href = nextUrl; },
        modal: true,
        show: 'blind',
        title: title
    }).dialog('widget')
                .next(".ui-widget-overlay")
                .css("background", "#737373");
    $("#some-Message").append(message);
    $("#some-Message").dialog('open');
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('background', '#737373');
}
```